# If $z = -2 + 2\sqrt{3}i$ and the value of $z^{2023!}+z^{2024!}+z^{2025!}=N$, then the last digit of N is . . .?

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, complex-numbers

I saw this question while preparing for my test which is happening on the 4th of June (and if you are too curious to know what test, we call it the IIT JEE exam or JEE ADVANCE exam) in complex numbers.

> **Q.** If $z=-2+2*\sqrt{3}i$ and the value of
> $z^{2023!}+z^{2024!}+z^{2025!}=N$, then the last digit of N is

> **My observations**
>
> I realised that this question revolves around only a single concept:
>
> **$w^{3k}=1$ where $3k$ is any multiple of $3$**
>
> So on factoring out 4 from $z$, then we realise $z=4w$

**My doubt:**

Now to proceed I must judge the factorial powers of $z$ and determine whether $2023!$, $2024!$ and $2025!$ are multiples of $3$ or not. How do we do this?

I would really be grateful if someone could explain just that part.

Comment: @MathFail Ok thanks, corrected

Comment: they are all multiples of 3

Comment: @MathFail Yes how do you know that?

Comment: what is a factorial?

Comment: @MathFail 3 factorial means 3*2*1...similarly 4! is 4*3*2*1

Comment: so they are all multiples of 3

Comment: @MathFail Oh yes I get it, so all the factorials are multiples of 3 right? Damn

Comment: yes, that's correct!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too long for a comment so I would add it here.

I assume  you had difficulty in calculating the end digit of $z^{2023!} + z^ {2024!} + z^{2025!}$, since we are involved with powers $4$, you could start writing down some powers of 4 and note down some general observations which you could find, which can aid us in solving the problem.

Like: $4^{2n} \equiv 6$ (mod 10) and $4^{2n+1} \equiv 4$ (mod 10) for $n >0$. Hence we can write, $64^{2n}\equiv 6 $ (mod 10), as $64^{2n}=4^{6n}$.

$z=4e^{i\cdot \frac{2 \pi}{3}}$, $z^3=64$, its always preferable to  work with $z^3$since it's an integer, hence the following manipulations were made:

$z^{2023!} + z^ {2024!} + z^{2025!}= 64^\frac{{2023!}}{3}+64^{\frac{2024!}{3}}+64^{\frac{2025!}{3}}=64^{2a}+64^{2b}+64^{2c}$, for some $a,b,c \in N$
as$\frac{2023!}{3},\frac{2024!}{3},\frac{2024!}{3}$ are all even as they contains factors of $2$.

$64^{2a}+64^{2b}+64^{2c} \equiv 6+6+6 $ ( mod 10), $18 \equiv 8$(mod 10), hence our answer is $8$.